# The Weibull distribution in R (ExtDist)

Tags: r, distribution, weibull

Has anyone had problems with the Weibull distribution using the [ExtDist Package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ExtDist/versions/0.6-3)?

From the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ExtDist/versions/0.6-3/topics/Weibull):

> Parameter Estimation for a distribution with unknown shape parameters
>   Example from: Rinne (2009) Dataset p.338 and example pp.418-419
>   Parameter estimates are given as shape = 99.2079 and scale = 2.5957.
>   The log-likelihood for this data and Rinne's parameter estimates is
>   -1163.278.

```
data <- c(35,38,42,56,58,61,63,76,81,83,86,90,99,104,113,114,117,119,141,183)
est.par <- eWeibull(X=data, method="numerical.MLE"); est.par
plot(est.par)
```

However when I run this I get the following output:

```
Parameters for the Weibull distribution.
(found using the  numerical.MLE method.)

 Parameter  Type   Estimate       S.E.
     shape shape 5.82976007 1.79326460
     scale scale 0.06628166 0.02129258
```

This is clearly wrong but I am not sure if I have made a mistake or if there is a bug in the package?

Comment: did you read the next bit of the example? "# Estimates calculated by eWeibull differ from those given by Rinne(2009). However, eWeibull's parameter estimates appear to be an improvement, due to a larger
 log-likelihood of -99.09037 (as given by lWeibull below)."

Comment: Hi Ben, yes I did but the answer I got from the code of 5.82976007 is definitely not even close, the output should be in the region of 99

Comment: Appears the quoted values are interchanged, aside from other problems noted by Ben B. Mean value for a Weibull distribution is gamma(1 + 1/shape) times scale, and that should be not too different from the mean of the data. For shape = 99 and scale = 2.6, the mean is very implausible, but very plausible if swapped. Also, I tried the data with a hand-rolled function and got shape = 2.6, scale = 99. I guess it's an open question as to whether the parameters are stated correctly in Rinne's paper, or correct there and incorrect in the quotation. For the record I tried 0.6-4 (most recent version).

Comment: For the record, the bugs in ExtDist have been corrected in version 0.7-1 as described by @notch below.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me it's a bug in the package.  I did my own independent MLE and got the same answer as Rinne:

```
library(bbmle)
m1 <- mle2(y~dweibull(shape=exp(lshape),scale=exp(lscale)),
     data=data.frame(y=data),
     start=list(lshape=0,lscale=0))
```

Then I dug in and looked at the source of the `dWeibull` function:

```
function (x, shape = 2, scale = 2, params = list(shape = 2, scale = 2)) 
{
    if (!missing(params)) {
        shape <- params$shape
        scale <- params$scale
    }
    out = stats::dgamma(x, shape, scale)
    return(out)
}
```

It seems that `out` should be set to the result of `dweibull(...)` rather than `dgamma(...)` ... ??  Looking at the rest of the weibull code, this error seems to be repeated -- maybe this is just a sloppy cut-and-paste?  I would definitely contact the maintainer (`maintainer("ExtDist")`).

PS. If I fit a Gamma distribution using my alternative method I get exactly the same answers as the `ExtDist` package:

```
m1g <- mle2(y~dgamma(shape=exp(lshape),rate=exp(lrate)),
     data=data.frame(y=data),
     start=list(lshape=0,lrate=0))
exp(coef(m1g))
##     lshape      lrate 
## 5.82976007 0.06628166
```

Answer (score 1):

Bugs affected code of eGamma and eWeibull, but this has now been fixed (v0.7-1, Jan 17, 2023). Thanks to Robert Dodier for pointing at them.

Current output of eWeibull:

```
# Parameter Estimation for a distribution with unknown shape parameters
# Example from: Rinne (2009) Dataset p.338 and example pp.418-419
# Parameter estimates are given as shape = 2.5957 and scale = 99.2079.
data <- c(35,38,42,56,58,61,63,76,81,83,86,90,99,104,113,114,117,119,141,183)
est.par <- eWeibull(X=data, method="numerical.MLE"); est.par

Parameters for the Weibull distribution. 
(found using the  numerical.MLE method.)

Parameter  Type Estimate      S.E.
    shape shape  2.59566 0.4366932
    scale scale 99.20792 9.0404336

# consistent with EnvStats estimates
EnvStats::eweibull(data)$parameters
    shape     scale 
 2.595663 99.207982
```

Current output of eGamma:

```
# Parameter estimation for a distribution with unknown shape parameters
# Example from:  Bury(1999) pp.225-226, parameter estimates as given by Bury are
# shape = 6.40 and scale=2.54.
data <- c(16, 11.6, 19.9, 18.6, 18, 13.1, 29.1, 10.3, 12.2, 15.6, 12.7, 13.1,
          19.2, 19.5, 23, 6.7, 7.1, 14.3, 20.6, 25.6, 8.2, 34.4, 16.1, 10.2, 12.3)
est.par <- eGamma(data, method="numerical.MLE"); est.par

Parameters for the Gamma distribution. 
(found using the  numerical.MLE method.)

Parameter  Type Estimate      S.E.
    shape shape 6.404003 1.7661637
    scale scale 2.544659 0.7300405

# consistent with EnvStats estimates
EnvStats::egamma(data)$parameters
    shape    scale 
 6.404041 2.544643
```