# Weibull distribution with weighted data

Tags: r, distribution, weighted, weibull

I have some time to event data that I need to generate around 200 shape/scale parameters for subgroups for a simulation model. I have analysed the data, and it best follows a weibull distribution.
Normally, I would use the fitdistrplus package and `fitdist(x, "weibull")` to do so, however this data has been matched using kernel matching and I have a variable of weighting values called `km` and so needs to incorporate a weight, which isn't something `fitdist` can do as far as I can tell.
With my gamma distributed data instead of using `fitdist` I did the calculation manually using the `wtd.mean` and `wtd.var` functions from the `hsmisc` package, which worked well. However, finding a similar formula for the weibull is eluding me.

I've been testing a few options and comparing them against the fitdist results:

```
test_data <- rweibull(100, 0.676, 946)
fitweibull <- fitdist(test_data, "weibull", method = "mle", lower = c(0,0))
fitweibull$estimate
shape          scale
0.6981165      935.0907482
```

I first tested this: [The Weibull distribution in R (ExtDist)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208176/the-weibull-distribution-in-r-extdist)

```
library(bbmle)
m1 <- mle2(y~dweibull(shape=exp(lshape),scale=exp(lscale)),
 data=data.frame(y=test_data),
 start=list(lshape=0,lscale=0))
```

which gave me `lshape = -0.3919991` and `lscale = 6.852033`

The other thing I've tried is `eweibull` from the `EnvStats` package.

```
eweibull <- eweibull(test_data)
eweibull$parameters
shape       scale
0.698091    935.239277
```

However, while  these are giving results, I still don't think I can fit my data with the weights into any of these.

Edit: I have also tried the similarly named `eWeibull` from the `ExtDist` package (which I'm not 100% sure still works, but does have a weibull function that takes a weight!). I get a lot of error messages about the inputs being non-computable (NA or infinite). If I do it with `map`, so `map(test_data, test_km, eWeibull)` I get [[NULL] for all 100 values. If I try it just with test_data, I get a long string of errors associated with optimx.

I have also tried `fitDistr` from `propagate` which gives errors that `weights` should be a specific length. For example, if both are set to be 100, I get an error that `weights` should be length 94. If I set it to 94, it tells me it has to be length of 132.

I need to be able to pass either a set of pre-weighted mean/var/sd etc data into the calculation, or have a function that can take data and weights and use them both in the calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I edited the `eweibull` function from the `EnvStats` package to instead of using `mean(x)` and `sd(x)`, to instead use `wtd.mean(x,w)` and `sqrt(wtd.var(x, w))`. This now runs and outputs weighted values.